# Using enviroment variables in a dockerfile RUN command

Tags: ubuntu, docker, dockerfile

Im trying to create an image through a dockerfile. But it returns an error.

## Nginx Dockerfile

```
RUN sudo apt-get install software-properties-common -y
RUN nginx=stable
RUN echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx/$nginx/ubuntu lucid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/nginx-$nginx-lucid.list
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys C300EE8C
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install nginx
```

Error message:

```
W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/nginx//ubuntu/dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found

E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
Fetched 21.3 MB in 59s (355 kB/s)
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update' returned a non-zero code: 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You are making the mistake of assuming this:

```
RUN nginx=stable
```

Will set an environment variable which you can then access. This is unfortunately not the case.

---

To create enviroment variables in [a dockerfile](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/), you use the [**`ENV`**](http://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#env) command; in its most simplistic form, you can define your env. variable as:

```
ENV nginx stable # define it
```

Then the substitution of `$nginx` with `stable` will be performed correctly in the consequent `RUN` commands.

***Additional notes:***

*First*, you should add `-y` to your last `RUN` command so it doesn't fail:

```
RUN apt-get install nginx -y
```

*Second*, you should consider chaining the `RUN` commands together with `&&` to reduce the number of layers created.